# Store output of Java main method in maven property

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a java class which encrypts text and prints in console for certain input

for eg

```
class A{
public static void main(String args[]){
sysout(encrypt(args[0],args[1]));
}
```

I am trying below in my pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.A</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>e</argument>
                        <argument>abc</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I wanted to call this java class and get encrypted value stored in maven variable during build phase.
So that it is used in later phases.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is it you really want to do?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen @ Vlad L There nothing failing, I am successfully anle to run the java file but cannot capture the output of java program, which I actually needed in deploy phase of maven, so I was thinking of storing it in maven properties and use it at later phase. I hope this clears it. Let me know if more info required

Comment: Why do you need encrypted values in the deploy phase?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you are holding plain-text deployment passwords in your sources.  That is not a good idea, and you should reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to maven properties document http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties, properties come in five different styles:

1. env.X: shell's environment variable
2. project.x: A dot (.) notated path in the POM will contain the corresponding element's value
3. settings.x: A dot (.) notated path in the settings.xml will contain the corresponding element's value
4. Java System Properties: All properties accessible via java.lang.System.getProperties()
5. x: Set within a  element in the POM

So, I think you can save your encrypted value into Java System Properties in your main code, and then get it use ${java.encryptValue} in pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was not thinking in that direction, let me try it out will revert back then